# With Paypal automatically send invoices

Tags: php, api, paypal, billing

I've seen many times before, that automatically after a payment with "PayPal express checkout" a bill (with taxes, ...) is sent by mail.

Now I looked at the PHP APIs for express checkout (x.com, paypal.com) - but I could only find bills for manual requesting money. How can I implement this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the "[DoAuthorization](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoAuthorization)" method then "[DoCapture](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_DoCapture)" to ensure that the funds are automatically requested. Once that is complete it should send an email to the buyer.